# Check if a script completed executing instead of exiting

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working with a script that I cannot modify, that does not use exit codes. (all exits are simply 'exit')

Without modifying the script (or yelling at the idiots who wrote it), is there a way to check if the script "got to the end" instead of exiting at some point earlier in the script?

The only thing I can think of is somehow tracking active processes until it ends, but it would also end when it exits due to an error.

Comment: `bash -x scriptname` will show you everything that the script does.  Looking at the last few lines of output should tell if it exited where you wanted it to.

Comment: Interesting solution - is there a way to pipe all of the -x output to file so it doesn't clutter the screen for the user + I can delete the file after execution?

Comment: If you don't want the screen clutter, run `bash -x scriptname | tail -n5` and it will display only the last 5 lines.

Comment: That only pipes the script output, not the output generated by using -x. edit : -x sends to stderr, using 2> logfile worked, going to post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working with a script that I cannot modify, that does not use exit codes.
>
> If there's an error, the last line in that file should contain 'exit', otherwise the script finished executing successfully.

This code will cause the command to exit with code 1 if it failed and code 0 if it succeeded:

```
bash -x scriptname 2>&1 | tail -n1 | grep -vq exit
```

`tail -n1` displays just the last line and `grep -vq exit` tests whether that line contained the word `exit`.

Examples of how to make this display useful messages:

```
bash -x scriptname 2>&1 | tail -n1 | grep -vq exit && echo Success
```

Or:

```
bash -x scriptname 2>&1 | tail -n1 | grep -vq exit || echo Fail
```